# GAS simple script not working

Tags: loops, google-apps-script

I have a script that is "by the book" according to Google and it's not working.

```
function capacityAlert() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("counts");
var currentValue = sheet.getRange("D2:D13").getValues();
Logger.log('currentValue = '+currentValue);
var nRows = currentValue.length;
for(var i=0;i<nRows;i++)
{
    //Logger.log(currentValue[i][0]);
    Logger.log('row '+i+' col[0] = '+currentValue[i][0]);
    if(currentValue[i][0]=="true")
    {
      Browser.msgBox("Capacity Reached");
        //MailApp.sendEmail("dave@davelalande.com","Capacity Reached","Capacity Reached, \nplease check the sheet and remove the date.");
    }  
}
}
```

Here is what the log says.

```
currentValue = false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true
row 0 col[0] = false
row 1 col[0] = false
row 2 col[0] = false
row 3 col[0] = false
row 4 col[0] = false
row 5 col[0] = false
row 6 col[0] = false
row 7 col[0] = false
row 8 col[0] = false
row 9 col[0] = false
row 10 col[0] = false
row 11 col[0] = true
```

It's not mailing so I am trying to create a popup just to see if the script it working.  I have turned off and tested my pop using a three line pop up script that is working, so I know popups are working.

Debug is blank?  What am I missing?

Thanks for any help you can throw my way.

Dave

Comment: Can you check the type of  currentValue[I][0] using typeOf() in the logger? Not sure it is a string... if not, add .toString() in the first term of the comparison.

Comment: When you put "true" in the spreadsheet, does it make it all capital letters automatically?

Comment: Serge I am working on the syntax for the Logger to check the type.  Bear with me...  I didn't know what the logger was till you showed me last week.  :)

Comment: Phil it is all caps in the spreadsheet.

Comment: you might try: if(currentValue[i][0])  if the values are boolean.

Comment: It looks like if(currentValue[i][0]==true) worked @ScampMichael

Comment: Now I am going to work on a separate email for each row that is true.  I got this separate to work if I setup a variable for each cell I was looking for true, but now that I am looping I want to set it back up properly.  I want to be as efficient in the code as possible.  You guys are awesome BTW.  Thanks for taking my under your wing.  I have definitely caught the GAS bug.  :)

Comment: sorry for misspelling typeof, the syntax is   `Logger.log(typeof(currentValue[i][0]))` , you will probably get 'boolean' which means Michael was right and that you can omit the `==true` in you condition, that's how boolean logic works...That's also why it shows up in capitals in your sheet (so Phil was right too ;-) and finally it was not a string (so I was right too ^^) So everybody is happy ...

Comment: It's great to be happy! Serge, how do you highlight in comments? Makes much easier to comprehend.

Comment: @Michael he he... I certainly do agree ! I use this smal character `````` I don't remember how I found that but it must be written somewhere ;-) btw it is not (apparently) available on my mac keyboard so I have a couple of them in a 'sticky' that's on my desktop... if ever you find an easier way to get it I'm on the list !

Comment: @Dave -if you have some free time please post your own answer to this post so it will be closed...(well at least not stay 'unanswered') I guess it's such a 'collective' answer that none of us will dare to post an answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me on this one.

```
 if(currentValue[i][0]==true)
```

Thanks to the guys here ScampMichael, Serge and Phil for their help always.